# fail to align two elements in html file

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

I have two buttons that I want to align to be in the same line, and for some reason the second one is below the first one...

I thought grouping them in one div will help.

this is my current html, there is probably some difficulty with my attempt to group `<md-switch>` with `<button>`.

```
<div>
    <button md-button (click)="publish()" class="md-primary">Update</button>
    <md-switch [(checked)]="data.cb1">Sho: {{ data.cb1 }}</md-switch>
</div>
```

If I am adding a style attribute to it, only the button reacts, so obviously something is going on with the md-switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<md-switch>` is a `directive` and no button. So the HTML will be replaced/parsed by angular which (as I think) outputs a block-level element.
Solutions for that would be to use either `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;`.
`display: inline-block;` is easier but will add 1px margin to your elements.
For floats the `<button>` has to be `display: block;`, too.